# Вложенность в сущности Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp-net-core-mvc

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли реализовать вложенность в сущности EF.

У меня есть простая модель, не понимаю как ее связать саму с собой:

```
public class Departament
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

У кого ParentId == 0 => группа.
Если ParantId != 0 значит этот элемент входит в группу.
[image: Таблица в SQL]

Вот не знаю как реализовать связь, чтобы при получении сущности из бд, подтягивался дочерний список...

Буду рад если направите по правильному пути)

P.S Использую EF Core 3.1

Comment: Возможно, лучшим выбором будет использовать `HierarchyId`. Первый попавшийся туториал: [Using SQL Server HierarchyId with Entity Framework Core](https://www.meziantou.net/using-hierarchyid-with-entity-framework-core.htm)

Comment: Могу направить по правильному пути: отказаться от EF и взять linq2db - эта ORM поддерживает [Common Table Expression](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/CTE.html). Или хотя бы возьмите дополнение [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

Answer (score 0):

Вот ссылки на полезный ресурс по этой теме
EF Core[ссылка](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/)
EF6 [ссылка](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/1.1.php)

Comment: Ресурсы, может быть, и полезные, но ссылки не являются ответом на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал вот так:

```
 public class Departament
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Departament Parent { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Departament> SubDepartaments { get; } = new List<Departament>();

}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Departament>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            entity.Property(x => x.Name);
            entity.HasOne(x => x.Parent)
                .WithMany(x => x.SubDepartaments)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });
    }
```